# Increasing computation speed of my comparison code for large table values

Tags: python, performance

I just started programming a couple of weeks ago. I'm working with 12 large data sets and need to make comparisons for values in specific columns of the tables. Each table contains `x-coordinates` (called 'X_IMA') and `y-coordinates` (called 'Y_IMA') as well as other data which isn't important for this comparison process. The data comes in 4 sets of 3 tables (which I will call **table 11**, **table 12**, **table 13**, for the tables of data set 1)

For example, I wish to compare **table 11** to **table 12** and **table 13** and check if there exists an `x-coordinate` that is equal to an `x-coordinate` in **table 2** and **table 3** (within some `+-` range). If so, I then want to check if the **y-coordinate** is equal and if that is the case, this is considered a match.

Additional data is written to a new file based on the matches. I want to compare matches for all 4 data sets. I'm using nested for loops and if statements to compare; however, the code takes **~2 hours** to run on a 20 core cluster which is terribly inefficient for debugging and ensuring that it actually works correctly. Is there anything I can do to clean up my code and shorten the runtime - either tidying up the loops to make them more efficient or is there another method of comparing large data sets in this way?

Any input would be greatly appreciated :)

Here is the code for just one set (of 4) of table comparisons:

```
    for x in range(0, len(table11)):
        for y in range(0, len(table12)):
            for z in range(0, len(table13)):
                if table12[y]["X_IMA"]-5<=table13[z]["X_IMA"]<=table12[y]["X_IMA"]+5 and table12[y]["Y_IMA"]-5<=table13[z]["Y_IMA"]<=table12[y]["Y_IMA"]+5 and table11[x]["X_IMA"]-5<=table13[z]["X_IMA"]<=table11[x]["X_IMA"]+5 and table11[x]["Y_IMA"]-5<=table13[z]["Y_IMA"]<=table11[x]["Y_IMA"]+5:
                    for i in range(0,20):,
                        if table11[x]["X_IMA"]-5<=reglistx[i]<=table11[x]["X_IMA"]+5 and table11[x]["Y_IMA"]-5<=reglisty[i]<=table11[x]["Y_IMA"]+5:
                            rateavg1[i]=(np.mean([table11[x]["RATE"],table12[y]["RATE"],table13[z]["RATE"]]))
```

`reglist` is a master list of x-y coordinates that I wish to compare the matched x-y coordinates of the 3 tables to and then extract data from the tables and write it to a file.

Again, any input, even little simple tips to increase computation speed would be a huge help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that is performing a 3-way comparison for all combinations of values (which is too much). So a first initial improvement would be to:

- Find out which indexes match ONLY between tables 11 & 12
- Then compare only the matching indexes with table 13
- Then compare only the matching indexes with your `reglist`

The most important thing here is the order in which you check the tables -  the smaller ones should come first (so if, for example, `table 11` is way bigger than the others, make sure that check it last).

A second improvement you can do is to sort your tables by `X_IMA` and `Y_IMA` values beforehand. In this way you can either:

- Stop scanning the second table in each comparison when it is clear that the value you are searching for is too low/high
- Use binary search to locate the set of records that are close to the one you are analysing.

There have to be even better ways of speeding up this further, but these strategies should show some improvement in your case anyway.

Also, it would improve the readability of your code if you define a function like this:

```
def is_close(x, y, delta=5):
    return abs(x-y) <= delta
```

And use it instead of these long if statements.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. I broke up the 3 way comparison into separate if statements comparing "X_IMA" first and then "Y_IMA" only if there's a match. I also reordered the loops so that the largest data set is compared last. In doing so, the previous run time of 2 hours was cut down to a whopping 16 seconds! :)